# Circular image edges are jagged in Alloy appcelerator

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-alloy

I am trying to make an circular image view in Alloy appcelerator formerly Titanium like this

XML

```
<ImageView id="profile_photo"  />
```

TSS

```
"#profile_photo_view_holder":{
    width: 80,
    height: 80,
    borderRadius: 40,
    borderWidth:2,
    borderColor:"black"     
}
```

The image view is rendering properly but jaggy in its edges looks like an anti aliasing problem.

I use image factory module to scale down also but no luck.

```
resizedImage = ImageFactory.imageAsResized(blob, {
    width : 80,
    height : 80,
    quality : 0.9
});
$.profile_photo.image = resizedImage;
```

Comment: are you developing your Android or iOS? On Android, there is a hack to also set the borderWidth which ensures to smooth the corners.

Comment: How it can be hacked ? can you elaborate please ?

Comment: You set a `borderWidth` to 1px which should smooth the corners.

Comment: borderWidth is already given and it is 1px only but the border is not jagged while it is clearly visible of image edges which are jagged. I am using 1280x720 resolution. Tested with native code in android which are rendering fine.

Comment: This might make a great feature request to improve how this is rendered. Stack Overflow is [not the right place](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company) for that. Please check if it has already been requested at the [Appcelerator JIRA](https://jira.appcelerator.org/). If it has not, create a ticket, link to this question but also provide a complete description in the ticket. Don't forget to drop a link to the ticket here so that others can watch it with you.

Answer (score 2):

on Android you will need to make use of a module to achieve it.
This module is quite new and looks great:

https://github.com/m1ga/com.miga.roundview

I'm using this one in my project:
https://github.com/snowciety/sc.roundedavatar

Hope it helps